# Замена типа данных в столбце

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Анализируя данные из csv файла, я вывел следующий датафрейм:

```
nd = data[['Дата операции', 'Сумма операции', 'Категория', 'Описание', 'Бонусы (включая кэшбэк)']]
```

Датафрейм показал нужную мне ленту операций, но в столбце 'Сумма операции' - строчные значения. 
Из-за этого не получается вывести корректно сумму затрат по категориям:

```
nd.groupby(['Категория'])['Сумма операции'].sum()
```

Как можно сменить тип данных в столбце "Cумма операции"?

На данный момент все данные типа 'object'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно просто:

```
df['something'] = pd.to_numeric(df['something'], errors='coerce')
```

**UPDATE**

Если в приводимом типе вместо десятичной точки - запятая:

```
df['something'] = pd.to_numeric(df['something'].str.replace(',','.'), errors='coerce')
```

Comment: ValueError: Unable to parse string "-360,00" at position 0


Выдает такую ошибку на первом же элементе, тоже пробовал, но накосячил с синтаксисом ранее. Из-за того, что это вещественное число, но вместо точки там стоит запятая? (360,00)

Comment: Вероятно потому, что у вас там десятичная запятая, а не точка.

Comment: А как заменить можно запятую во всем столбце на точку? 
Спасибо за предыдущий ответ, теперь хоть понял, что есть рабочий метод.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Я так понимаю str.replace не работает с переменными object?
Наверно тогда стоит сначала привести столбец к строчным значениям, потом заменить "," и только затем приводить к числовому варианту значению

Comment: Все сработало, спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Тип object в pandas это и есть строковый тип. Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.